# JQuery/PHP - Breaking up a bunch of ajax requests into batches?

Tags: php, jquery

**UPDATE:** Seems like I have been wasting my time to some extent as according to http://www.browserscope.org/?category=network&v=top-d most modern browsers already limit the number of connections to a single host. 6 being the common number of connections which suits my purposes rather well. But I guess it is still an interesting problem.

The final piece of the jigsaw for my work task is break a list of potentially 250+ ajax requests into batches.

As the result of the following php code

```
<?
// print("alert(\" booya \");");
  $hitlist = array();
  $hitlist = urlBuilder($markets,$template);
  foreach ($hitlist as $mktlist) {
      foreach ($mktlist as $id => $hit) {
          $cc = substr($id,0,2);
          $lc = substr($id,-4);
          echo ("$(\"#" . $cc . $lc . "\").load(\"psurl.php?server=" . $server . "&url=" . $hit . "&port=" . $port . "\");\n");
      }
  }
?>
```

This generates a long list of jquery .load's which right now are all executed on a click.

e.g.

```
$("#sesv-1").load("psurl.php?server=101.abc.com&url=/se/sv&port=80");
$("#sesv-2").load("psurl.php?server=101.abc.com&url=/se/sv/catalog/&port=80");
$("#sesv-3").load("psurl.php?server=101.abc.com&url=/se/sv/catalog/products/12345678&port=80");
$("#atde-1").load("psurl.php?server=101.abc.com&url=/at/de&port=80");
$("#atde-2").load("psurl.php?server=101.abc.com&url=/at/de/catalog/&port=80");
$("#atde-3").load("psurl.php?server=101.abc.com&url=/at/de/catalog/products/12345678&port=80");
$("#benl-1").load("psurl.php?server=101.abc.com&url=/be/nl&port=80");
$("#benl-2").load("psurl.php?server=101.abc.com&url=/be/nl/catalog/&port=80");
$("#benl-3").load("psurl.php?server=101.abc.com&url=/be/nl/catalog/products/12345678&port=80");
$("#befr-1").load("psurl.php?server=101.abc.com&url=/be/fr&port=80");
$("#befr-2").load("psurl.php?server=101.abc.com&url=/be/fr/catalog/&port=80");
$("#befr-3").load("psurl.php?server=101.abc.com&url=/be/fr/catalog/products/12345678&port=80");
```

Depending on circumstances it can be like 250 requests or perhaps only 30-40. The whole purpose of the app is to warm up newly restarted appservers... so 250 requests in a new jvm = death!

So ideally I would like to break them up. Perhaps by the market would be best meaning at most 5-6 requests at a time.

Any ideas on how this can be accomplished? Is it possible in standard jquery? Trying to make the dependencies as limited as possible so preferably without plugins!

Comment: If you mean wait until X number of requests finish, figure out what you want X to be and run them all in a `setTimeout` using a `count` variable to limit the number of queries run.

Comment: hmm - yes and I guess even better than that would be to set x=5 there always be 5 running. i.e. when one request finishes the count is down to 4, so it starts a new one. Rather than waiting for x=0 and then starting 5 more.

Comment: If it works for you, then yes that solution would ensure 5 are always running, instead of 5 at a time.

Comment: Do you have a little example to go on? I'm fannying around with and getting nowhere :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's [.queue](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.queue/).

```
// Define a queue for execution
var
$elem = $("#sesv-1"),
enqueue = function(a){ $elem.queue("status", a) };

// Queue your requests
enqueue(function(a){
  $aElem.load("url", a);
});

enqueue(function(a){
  $otherElem.load("url", a);
});

// Execute the queue
$elem.dequeue("status");
```

You can create as many queues as you need (most probably per market) then enqueue your requests.

Comment: Having only read up on it for a few minutes I may be missing something but the queue is of a fixed size right? i.e. '1' In other words it becomes synchronous and and that is the reason I am rewriting this stuff, so that it can be asyncronous .... Sure is faster doing 250 requests simultaneously... a 25000% increase you might say :) But it's too much for the scenario. We would be more than happy with a 500% performance increase for 5 hits simultaneously instead of the crap old cgi synchronous script!

Comment: @Seer, as I said you can create multiple queues and execute them all. Let's say 5 of them.